# saving textarea input's value in to js variable and make it visible everywhere

Tags: javascript, global-variables

HTML:

```
<textarea id="edit-message"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="guest-button" class="form-submit">Send</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#guest-button').click(function() {
    if (window.sessionStorage){
        sessionStorage.setItem("gbookmsg", $('#edit-message').val())
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.replace("http://anti-idol.org/user/login");
    }, 500);
});

$('#edit-message').val(gbookmsg);
```

What i want to achieve is when a user fills textarea inputs with some text and then clicking to a send button - it will save the value of the textarea in to a `gbookmsg` variable. Then when user is redirected to a login page - after he successfully logs in, he goes back to this form and javascript inserts `gbookmsg` input's value filled previously. But when the page reloads my `gbookmsg` variable is getting undefined. How to save it? Thanks

Comment: You could persist it in a cookie and then look it up. Or you could send it with the form and pass it through the login process and back down to the client with the response.

Comment: Can you throw me an example with a cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot achieve this by global variable as the scope of the global variable is for time the DOM is available if the page is reloaded the value will be lost

1. you can either use cookies

or

1. use DOM [sessionStorage](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/domstorage.shtml) or [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

   ```
   if (window.sessionStorage){
    sessionStorage.setItem("gbookmsg ", $('#edit-message').val()) ;
   }
   ```

**EDIT**

Created the <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/AfhGR/3/)</kbd> for you

- Run for the first time you will see a blank alert
- Set the value and reload the page.

Comment: You have save that value oustside the DOM either in cookies or webstorage.

Comment: Can you make an example for my case please.

Answer (score 1):

Use cookies in order to store variables.

Please, see the following article which helps you to store and retrieve values from cookies by using JQuery:
http://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/

Comment: As I can see, yes, it does. It depends on jquery 1.0 or higher. 

See the dependencies section here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/cookie.jquery.json

`"jquery": ">=1.0"`

Answer (score 0):

What backend are you using? You can either store the data into the session (server side) or use query string to pass the values to the next page. Or you can use cookie to store the value

Answer (score 0):

Global variables only live as long as the page, when the page gets reloaded, they are lost.

You have a few options for storage more persistant than a page:

#### localStorage

localStorage is an object which does persist between page loads:

```
localStorage.cat = 3;
// After a page load:
alert(localStorage.cat) // will alert '3'
```

#### Cookies

You can use document.cookie to set a browser cookie which will remember the value.

#### Passing it in the redirect

If you pass the text from the input through each step of the login redirect, you can have it back when the page loads.

The login redirect might look like:

```
http://myawesomedomain.com/login?redirect=http://myawesomedomain.com/contact?message=Hi!
```

Then that would redirect you after login to:

```
http://myawesomedomain.com/contact?message=Hi!
```

and you can pull the message out of the get parameter.